# Add dashed-line border for PdfPcell in PdfPtable using itext?

Tags: android, itext

How to add Dashed-line Border to PdfPcell in PdfPTable using iText in android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the border of the cell to `NO_BORDER` and define a `PdfPCellEvent` instead. Draw the border in the event, using a line dash pattern.

For cell events, see http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=201

For dashed lines and drawing rectangles, see [PathConstructionAndPainting](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=241) and [GraphicsStateOperators](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=242).

Comment: Huh, somebody voted this answer down? That's odd as using a cell event is the easiest way to achieve this (using a table event is the other way, but that's more difficult).

Comment: Please have a look on the edited question and help to solve the issue.

Comment: The question is a month old. The answer was accepted. If you have an additional question, post a new question. I know the answer to your question, but I won't answer it here as it's a different question than the one you originally posted.